# Fetching image from iOS CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, uiimage

I have a Core Data entity defined with an `NSData` property `imageData`. I have a setter and getter setup for `image` on the entity.

The setter, `setImage`, just calls `[self setImageData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)];`
The getter, `image`, just returns `[UIImage imageWithData:[self imageData]];`

When I create a new entity and my fetched results controller loads the new table row, **the image always pulls null**. However, **if I tap the row to go to the next view controller, the image shows up just fine**.

What can I do to make it show the image immediately after the save occurs and the fetchResultsController updates with the new row.

EDIT: Adding code

Core data header and getter/setter for image snippet

```
.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * imageData;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;

.m
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [self setImageData:data];
}

- (UIImage *)image
{
    return [UIImage imageWithData:[self imageData]];
}
```

Table view code

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Artists"];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ArtistModel" inManagedObjectContext:[[BKDataManager sharedInstance] mainObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[[BKDataManager sharedInstance] mainObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Artists"];

    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ArtistTableViewCell *cell = (ArtistTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ArtistsTableViewCell"];

    if(!cell) {
        cell = (ArtistTableViewCell *)[[[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ArtistTableViewCell" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    ArtistModel *row = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [[cell artistNameLabel] setText:[row name]];
    [[cell artistImageView] setImage:[row image]]; // This is where it pulls from the artist model

    return cell;
}
```

Saving to core data bit

```
- (void)addArtistWithName:(NSString *)name confirmed:(BOOL)confirmed managedContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedContext success:(BKClientIdResult)success failure:(BKClientError)failure
{
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            name, @"name",
                            [NSNumber numberWithBool:confirmed], @"confirmed"
                            , nil];

    [[BKClient sharedInstance] postPath:@"/users/artists" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if([[responseObject objectForKey:@"status"] boolValue]) {
            NSDictionary *result = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"payload.artist"];

            ArtistModel *artistModel = (ArtistModel *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ArtistModel" inManagedObjectContext:managedContext];

            [artistModel setName:[result objectForKey:@"name"]];

                NSURLRequest *imageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[result objectForKey:@"image"]]];

                AFImageRequestOperation *op = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:imageRequest imageProcessingBlock:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                    [artistModel setImage:image];

                    [managedContext save:nil];

                    if(success) {
                        success(artistModel);
                    }
                } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                    // TODO FIX
                }];

                [op start];
        } else {
            if(failure) {
                failure([NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.nf" code:0 userInfo:[responseObject objectForKey:@"error"]]);
            }
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if(failure) {
            failure(error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, the simplest way to refresh data is to perform a new fetch (through the `NSFetchedResultsController`) and reload the table view when you have finished to save.

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    // error handling here...
}

[yourTableView reloadData];
```

Alternatively, you could think to set up the delegate for your `NSFetchedResultsController`. For further info, take a look here [NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller).

Setting this delegate, it allows you to listen for changes to your managed context and respond correctly to table view modifications (add, remove, update sections and rows).

P.S. If you provide some code, we will be able to help you in a more detailed manner.

Comment: I've added some code, my apologies for not doing so in the first place, was a bit scatter brained trying to sort it out.

Comment: @nullfox What does `success(artistModel)` do? What about the delegate for `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: @nullfox Before `if(success){...}` put the code I provided and see what happens. You should provide the code relative to methods of `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`.

Comment: In this case, the success block does this:
`[[self artistTextField] setText:@""];
        
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ArtistsUpdatedNotification" object:nil];
        
[SVProgressHUD dismiss];`

The notification is being observed by the controller and calls a method which does the following:

`_fetchedResultsController = nil;
    
[[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:nil];`

Comment: @nullfox reload also table data in that block

Comment: simply adding [[self tableView] reloadData] in the method that was observing the notification seems to have resolved it

Comment: @nullfox you don't need to set to nil the fetched controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSValueTransformer` to easily store image into CoreData (use `Transformable` type instead of `NSData`):

.h

```
@interface ImageToDataTransformer : NSValueTransformer

@end
```

.m

```
#import "DataTransformer.h"

@implementation ImageToDataTransformer

#pragma mark - UIImage to NSData

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation {
  return YES;
}

+ (Class)transformedValueClass {
  return [NSData class];
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
  NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(value);
  return data;
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
  UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:value];
  return [image autorelease];
}

@end
```

And don't forget to set your attribute as `Transformable` type, then in "Data Model Inspector", set the name to `ImageToDataTransformer`.

Comment: Kjuly, nullfox said "if I tap the row to go to the next view controller, the image shows up just fine". So, I think it is a problem due to data refresh. But with no details it is difficult to understand what is going on.